# SWING JTable changes view after sorting table using column header

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in which rows get disabled after selection of combo box item. But when I sort the table using table sorter on column head, value which comes on present enabled row will be enabled and not which was enabled after selection of combo item.

Comment: This has a lot to do with how you are managing the model and view, without a runnable example that demonstrates your problem it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: You mean you want to see the code., Problem is it is in two different classes., orelse I would have placed a snippet of code. Is there any alternative for this tablesorter which sorts along with the model...?

Comment: Have you tried something?? post your code and where you fail to get it.

Comment: @AnilB whatever it is! post your both classes we don't mind.

Comment: It just has to be a runnable example that demonstrates you problem, preferably self contained and compilable

Comment: Don't forget to convert between view and model indexes, as described in the API and tutorial.